# How can I validate MSAL token on API Management?

Tags: c#, azure-api-management, azure-ad-msal

I have a desktop app which uses ADAL for authentication, this app make requests to an API on the API Management azure service. After migrating the code to use MSAL, the API Management returns 401 saying that my token is invalid. The only difference that I see spying the requests is that ADAL makes a request to this endpoint `/tenantID/oauth2/token` and MSAL `/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token`.

In my API Management I have this policy:

```
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid. AAD" require-expiration-time="false">
         <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    </validate-jwt>
```

I tried to change the well known url to v2.0 endpoint but get the same error. How can I validate the token using MSAL?

Comment: May I know if it is helpful? If it helps, please accept it as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the *Note* in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#configure-a-jwt-validation-policy-to-pre-authorize-requests), when changing the well known url to v2.0, you may need to use `common` instead of `tenantID`.

```
<openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
```

Also, make sure you have done the step 10 in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#enable-oauth-20-user-authorization-in-the-developer-console) correctly:

> If you use v2 endpoints, use the scope you created for the backend-app
>   in the **Default scope** field. Also, make sure to set the value for
>   the [accessTokenAcceptedVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#accesstokenacceptedversion-attribute) property to `2` in your
>   [application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest).